# InfluxDB - Data loss for specific retention policy after service restart

Tags: raspberry-pi, influxdb, raspberry-pi4, data-loss

I have two retention policies set up, one for 2 weeks and one for 10 years.

It seems when the service starts, all recent (a couple of hours) data points for the 10-year retention policy are lost. I noticed this issue because the OS has killed the influxdb process due to out-of-memory conditions in the morning.

I can see data from 4 AM is still kept, but anything more recent stored with the ten_years RP is wiped from history after each ordinary restart of the service (it is around 10 AM now, so at least ~6 hrs of data).

The two_weeks RP is unaffected, all data points are kept between restarts and no data  for this RP was lost during the OOM event.

[image]If I were to restart the service again, i would see the recent data from the top graph disappear. New incoming points would then be rendered as can be seen here. This happens for every restart.

> root@raspberrypi:~# influxd version
>
> InfluxDB v1.8.7 (git: 1.8 v1.8.7)

The service runs on a Raspberry PI 4 with 8 GB of RAM, no swap, external SSD is used as boot device.

I performed manual restarts doing "systemctl restart influxd.service" and was able to reproduce the issue each time.
I can not see any indication of error or warning in the log file. There are no OOM conditions right now, data with the ten_year RP is lost whenever I do a graceful service restart. Already tried rebooting the Raspberry PI with no changes in behaviour.